# In Tableau dashboard I have a metric which i should display in kilos, Millions and Billions automatically

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a Measure in Tableau which has to be display dynamically in Kilos, Millions , Billions and also formatted as 200k, 2726M.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this formula which you can expand on your needs:

```
str(
if SUM([Sales]) > 1000000000 THEN ROUND(SUM([Sales])/1000000000,1)
elseif SUM([Sales]) > 1000000 THEN ROUND(SUM([Sales])/1000000,1)
elseif SUM([Sales]) > 1000 THEN ROUND(SUM([Sales])/1000,1)
else SUM([Sales])
end )
+
if SUM([Sales]) > 1000000000 THEN 'B'
elseif SUM([Sales]) > 1000000 THEN 'M'
elseif SUM([Sales]) > 1000 THEN 'K'
else ''
end
```

See screenshot as quick example on Superstore:
[image]

Comment: What's your result like? please take a look at the screenshot in the answer